# Select only cells in which the formula give numbers and not empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet on which I applied to all the cells the following formula:

`=IF(OR(A2="";B1="");""; IF(ISERR(VLOOKUP($A2&"-"&B$1;Sheet1!$D$1:$D$1000;1;FALSE));0;1))`

The formula gives `0` or `1` based on certain conditions and `""` (empty cell) if the conditions are not met.
Now, starting from these results, I'd like to select all the cells in the sheet giving as result 0 or 1, for further operations.
How can I do it, knowing that all these cells will not have empty spaces between?

Comment: what range or column(s) contain the formula?

Comment: When you say select, you don't mind hiding cells with empty values? If so, best bet would be `Filter`. Then select only visible cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
dim a as long, i as long, rng as range
with cells(1, "A").currentregion
    set rng = .specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlnumbers)
    for a=1 to rng.areas.count
        for i=1 to rng.areas(a).cells.count
            'do something with rng.areas(a).cells(i)
        next i
    next a
end with

'more simply as,
with cells(1, "A").currentregion
    .specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlnumbers).select
end with
```

You can also use F5 (GoTo), Special, Formulas, Numbers, OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jeeped, but I was looking for a selection of all the range at the same time and make the operations before. Do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: See the narrative at the end of my response.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted answer from Barry Carter:

In the Find and Replace dialog box, type "1" in the Find What box.
Click Find All, to see a list of cells with "1"
Select an item in the list, and press Ctrl+A, to select the entire list.

Now you have selected all of the cells with "1"

If you need to select all 0 and 1 you can go to Search & Select again,
Then to "Go To"
Then to "Special"
There if you select "Formulas" and "Numbers" you will end up selecting all of your 0 and 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pierre. And is it possible to search for 0 and 1 at the same time, so that it will select all the sheet range containing these values? Many thanks!

Comment: See my adjusted answer :)